# Passing props from component to componet using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have a component `ProfileDetails` that has a toggle function to toggle additional information on a profile. I'm importing `ProfileDetails` to a component `ProfileTable` and trying to pass `isOpen` with `ProfileDetails`. To then do a ternary operator with the condition isOpen. I am getting isOpen is undefined when doing so

ProfileDetails :

```
function ProfileDetails() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Button>
                <ArrowForwardIosIcon
                    size="small"
                    onClick={toggle}></ArrowForwardIosIcon>{" "}
            </Button>
            <Slider open={isOpen} />
        </>
    );
}
```

ProfileTable:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import format from "date-fns/format";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import DataTable from "../DataTable";
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos";
import ProfileDetails from "./ProfileDetails ";




function ProfileTable(props, isOpen) {
    const { classes } = props;



    const drawerColumns = [
        {
            name: "Name",
            label: "Name",
            options: {
                filter: true,
                sort: false,
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
                    return (
                        <Button size="small" onClick={() => {}}>
                            {value}
                        </Button>
                    );
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Address",
            label: "Address",
            options: {
                filter: false,
                sort: true
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Zip",
            label: "Zip",
            options: {
                filter: false,
                sort: true
            }
        },
        {
            name: "",
            label: "",
            options: {
                filter: false,
                sort: false,
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
                    return <ProfileDetails isOpen={isOpen} />;
                }
            }
        }
    ];

    const options = {

        search: false,
        print: false,
        download: false,
        selectableRows: "multiple",
        expandableRows: false
    };

    return isOpen ? (
        <DataTable
            title="Shifts to be Approved"
            data={details}
            columns={drawerColumns}
            options={options}
        />
    ) : (
        <DataTable
            title="Shifts to be Approved"
            data={details}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
        />
    );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ProfileTable);
```

Comment: Can you post the ProfileTable component in its entirity?

Comment: Updated post with entire component

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for updating your question. user8544110's answer is correct in terms of moving the state into the child component, else if you had more than one **ProfileTable** toggling one would toggle all.

**ProfileTable** has isOpen as undefined as functional components only have one parameter passed down for props which is an object of all the props passed to it. Therefore you can pick up the **isOpen** as follows:

```
    function ProfileTable(props) {
        const { classes, isOpen } = props;
        ...
    }
```

Or using arrow functions you can:

```
    const ProfileTable = ({ classes, isOpen }) => { 
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`isOpen` is `undefined` because your `ProfileDetails` component is not getting any prop in the definition of the functional component. If you want to use the component like that, you should do the following:

```
function ProfileDetails(isOpenProp) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(isOpenProp);

  const toggle = () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
      <>
        <Button>
            <ArrowForwardIosIcon
                size="small"
                onClick={toggle}></ArrowForwardIosIcon>{" "}
        </Button>
        <Slider open={isOpen} />
      </>
  );
}
```

That way, the initial value for `isOpen` would be the prop that you are passing from `ProfileTable`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use isOpen as a state of a component that is the parent of both **ProfileDetails** and **ProfileTable** and implement toggle function in that component too. Pass reference of the toggle function to **ProfileDetails**. Also, pass isOpen to **ProfileTable**. Now you can toggle the value of isOpen from **ProfileDetails** component and use that value in **ProfileTable** component.